# Failing to set up basic unit test solution with chutzpah, typescript and requirejs

Tags: requirejs, typescript, amd, qunit, chutzpah

For some reason, all of my (even basic) attempts to set up unit testing with Chutzpah, TypeScript and RequireJS fail miserably.

I tried several combinations based on the examples but either I get a timeout error or a file not found error (one which doesn't make any sense to me, since it's a Chutzpah-generated file). My guess would be that it's just something small (albeit not easy to find, perhaps), so maybe someone has an idea how I can resolve this error.

Testfile

```
/// <reference path="../../../typings/qunit/qunit.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../../typings/requirejs/require.d.ts" />

define([], () => {
    QUnit.module('DefineTests2');
    test('foo', () => {
        equal(0, 0);
    });
});
```

Output

```
------ Test started: File: C:\Users\...\test.DefineTests2.ts ------
Error: Error opening c:/users/.../Scripts/Game/Tests/Utilities/_Chutzpah.164.test.DefineTests2.js: The system cannot find the path specified.
While Running:C:\Users\...\Scripts\Game\Tests\Utilities\test.DefineTests2.ts
Error: Timeout occurred when executing test file
While Running:C:\Users\...\Scripts\Game\Tests\Utilities\test.DefineTests2.ts
========== Total Tests: 0 passed, 0 failed, 0 total ==========
```

chutzpah.json

```
{
    "Framework": "qunit",
    "TestHarnessReferenceMode": "AMD",
    "TestHarnessLocationMode": "SettingsFileAdjacent",
    "TypeScriptModuleKind": "AMD",
    "AMDBasePath": "Scripts/Game",
    "References": [ 
        { "Path": "Scripts/deps/requirejs/require.js" }, 
        { "Path" : "config.js" }
    ]
}
```

config.js

```
require.config({
    paths: {},
    shim: {}
});
```

Obviously this is already a very stripped down version, so hopefully any mistake should be easy to find for someone with more experience with Chutzpah.

---

**[Supplement]**

After changing Compilation mode to external (thanks Matthew Manela), the path looks a bit better, but something is still wrong, which I didn't notice earlier and additionally replaced with dots when I wrote this post, the displayed Path is missing two directories in its middle.

```
------ Test started: File: C:\Users\MyName\Source\Repos\MySolutionName\Main\MyProjectName\Scripts\Game\Tests\Utilities\test.DefineTests2.ts ------
Error: Error opening C:/Users/MyName/Source/Repos/MyProjectName/Scripts/Game/Tests/Utilities/test.DefineTests2.js: The system cannot find the path specified.
While Running:C:\Users\MyName\Source\Repos\MySolutionName\Main\MyProjectName\Scripts\Game\Tests\Utilities\test.DefineTests2.ts
Error: Timeout occurred when executing test file
While Running:C:\Users\MyName\Source\Repos\MySolutionName\Main\MyProjectName\Scripts\Game\Tests\Utilities\test.DefineTests2.ts
========== Total Tests: 0 passed, 0 failed, 0 total ==========
```

The line with "Error opening" has a slightly wrong path, it is missing \MySolutionName\Main, which explains why it doesn't find the file. The chutzpah.json is under MyProjectName, and so even Settings like TestHarnessLocationMode etc. shouldn't be related to that.

Comment: It is hard to debug with out a full repro (if you can provide one) but I do see one clear issues. You should be using the compile setting (https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/wiki/Compile-Setting) to tell chutzpah how to compile your files. If you don't do that it will use an old version of the TS compiler. Please take a look at this sample (https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/tree/master/Samples/RequireJS/TypeScript) which shows TypeSript + RequireJS.

Comment: I thought compilation through Chutzpah was optional. As all my TS files are configured for compile-after-save, all of them are always compiled to the latest state, thus any further compilation would not really make sense ;) Is there a way to disable compilation altogether?

Comment: That is fine to do but you need to let Chutzpah know that is what you are doing. See https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/tree/master/Samples/Compilation/ExternalCompile

Comment: Ah that makes sense, I must've misunderstood that part of the docs or something. Unfortunately it only helped partially, I explain the rest in the edited post

Comment: How are you telling chutzpah to find test.definetests2.js?

Comment: I invoked it with the VS Chutzpah Test Runner Context Menu Extension ... but to rule that out, I tried it with this command line executed from my solution directory: packages\Chutzpah.3.2.6\tools\chutzpah.console.exe MyProjectName\Scripts\Game\Tests\Utilities\test.DefineTests2.ts

Comment: So are the .js files you generate in the same folder as the corresponding .ts files? If not you need to tell chutzpah

Comment: Yes they are, the path that is output is correct, just that those two directories are missing

Comment: That is odd, can you please provide a repro?

Comment: Of course, it's available under http://tinyurl.com/lg67nxt . In this one, only one directory is missing in the output path, but it's also the solution directory. Very weird. But thanks for your help :)

Comment: @MatthewManela Were you able to reproduce this issue with my example project?

Comment: Is this still an issue? I lost track of this thread. Let me know if you still need help